# Test a React using async customHook

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, react-hooks

I would like to know if there was a specific way to test React component using async custom hook inside it.
I plan to use injection dependency so that I can pass custom hook as a prop and mock it in tests, but I haven’t seen anyone use a such pattern.
I know i could externalize custom hook inside an higher order component or a container and just pass resulting values from custom hook, but, I mean,it is not in the interest of not using them when using custom hooks?
Thanks by advance for yours answers.

Comment: Show the code under test

Comment: The idea is to use the tests to create the implementation, so it doesn’t exist yet. I’ll still try to add a schema in the day.